# Excel Concatenation Not Working

Tags: .net, excel, concatenation, ms-office

I have an Excel file in which I need to concat some colums and so far it is proving extremely hard to do it.

I did the thing as instructed in tutorials: select cells in columns to concatenate in the concat formula and just press the small box on the right bottom to apply it to the entire column.

And the image shows my situation.

I tried looking for solutions (Calculation is set to automatic) but nothing works.

Please help. Thanks.

I tried: Changing Format to general, executing each formula one by one (it just gives one repeated value).

[image]

Comment: What is `=CONCAT()`? Should it not be `=CONCATENATE()`? Are you using Excel 2016?

Comment: @TimWilkinson yes Excel 2016. I tried with both, same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect the cells with the formula are formatted as text. Change the number format to general and try entering the formula again.